# How can one configure the default screen recording program to record the audio by default?

Tags: audio, android-12, audio-recording, google-pixel-6, screencast

I use a Google Pixel 6 with Android 12.  How can one configure the default screen recording program to record the audio by default? I don't want to have to manually activate "Record audio" each time I record the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your concern, but you can't. That UX is a decision from Google's end and toggling it manually every time is the only option as of today.